# Retrieve access token from Third party OAuth providers

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to make a call to OAuth2.0 api from WCF service to retrieve accessToken.
I managed to call OAuth2.0 API sitting in Azure all okay using the code below:

```
            // Create confidential client application
        IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(oAuthAuthenticationConfig.ClientId)
                                                        .WithClientSecret(oAuthAuthenticationConfig.ClientSecret)
                                                        .WithAuthority(new Uri(oAuthAuthenticationConfig.Authority))
                                                        .Build();

    string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{oAuthAuthenticationConfig.ApiUrl}" };

  result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                              .ExecuteAsync();
```

No what I am not sure of how to use the same for OAuth2.0 API sitting in Google. The clientId that ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(CliendId) take as parameter must be a valid GUID while the Client Id that I gets generated from Google OAuth application is something like

```
 const string clientID = "879017285009-4igdmblu7i6b7djetijvjhc5p1h7v2ul.apps.googleusercontent.com";
```

Can I even use ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder defined in nuget Microsoft.Identity.Client for Google/Third part OAuth2.0 providers? If not what are my other options?

Answer (score 0):

The [Google.Apis.Auth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth/) package lets you authenticate as a service account and also takes care of refreshing access tokens before they expire. See [Authenticating as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) for some usage examples.

The equivalent to using `...WithClientSecret(...)` on Azure would be to authenticate by using a service account key on Google Cloud. However, if your service already has Azure credentials, it might also be an option to use [Workload identity federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/access-resources-azure) to exchange an Azure access token against a Google access token, saving you from having to manage another secret key.